# Flutter ListView в чём разница между key: UniqueKey() и GlobalKey()

Tags: listview, flutter

В ListView передаётся список. Необходимо по тапу удалять элемент из этого ListView. Когда в параметрах буилдера ListView не указан `key:` или указан но является `GlobalKey()` то при удалении элемента списка слетает нумерация элементов и список визуально отображается правильно, но если попробывать редактировать какой нибудь элемент, то у такого элемента будут не верные данные. Если же в случае когда в билдере ListView указан какой нибудь уникальный идентификатор, например `key: UniqueKey()` то поведение элементов ListView  становится корректным и предсказуемым, но после удаления любого элемента, список автоматически скроллится в самое начало, до первого его элемента. Хотелось бы удалять элемент из ListView так, что бы его поведение было после корректным, а сам ListView не скролился в самое начало.

Вот тут у меня хранится список который я перадаю в ListView

```
List<Channel> _editorChannels;
```

Так я удаляю элемент. Ищу его в списке по уникальному Id и удаляю.

```
onDelete(Channel c) {
    final f = _editorChannels.firstWhere((element) => element.Id == c.Id,
        orElse: () => null);
    if (f != null) setState(() => _editorChannels.remove(f));
  }
```

Вот так выглядит ListView , он внутри одной из вкладок DefaultTabController, я сокращенно только покажу код одной вкладки, что бы не так много кода было.

```
      Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Scaffold(
                  body: ListView.builder(
                      key: UniqueKey(),
                      itemCount: _editorChannels == null
                          ? 0
                          : _editorChannels.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final item = _editorChannels[index];
                        return Card(
                          shadowColor: Colors.black26,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                          ),
                          child: ListTile(
                              title: Container(
                                  child: Text(
                                item.Name != null ? item.Name : '',
                                style: new TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 16.0),
                              )),
                              subtitle: Text(item.Url),
                              onTap: () => {
                                    Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) =>
                                              ChewieDemo(channel: item)),
                                    )
                                  },
                              isThreeLine: false,
                              leading: getIconbyId(item.Status),
                              trailing: PopMenuWidget(
                                channel: item,
                                onDelete: () => onDelete(item),
                                onUpdate: (item) => onUpdate(item),
                              )),
                        );
                      }),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использование параметра `key: UniqueKey()` приводит к пересозданию виджета при каждой перерисовке экрана, т.к. созданное ранее представление виджета сопоставляется с новым по данному ключу, а этот ключ всегда уникален. Что касается ключа **GlobalKey**, то он особых изменений в механизм сопоставления виджета с отрисованным объектом не вносит, т.к. по сути является глобальной ссылкой на состояние виджета.

На вашем примере использование **UniqueKey** приводит к полному пересозданию ListView в его первоначальном состоянии, что помимо проблемы с сохранением текущей позиции, ещё и снижает производительность.

Кстати о производительности: созданный с помощью **ListView.builder** виджет использует оптимизацию и отрисовывает только видимые элементы списка и при прокрутке удаляет далеко ушедшие элементы. И второй момент, вероятно в вашем случае вызывающий "рассогласование" представления с моделью, это то, что при удалении элемента из модели старый элемент списка из представления не удаляется, а используется повторно с новыми аргументами. Если в элементе списка нет элементов со своим состоянием, то проблем это не вызывает. В противном случае stateful-виджет будет по прежнему использовать свое старое состояние, хотя через аргументы ему были переданы данные уже совсем другого элемента списка. В этом можно убедиться на простом [примере](https://codepen.io/sldsrg/pen/YzGXKoL):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: ListViewPitfall()));
}

class ListViewPitfall extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListViewPitfallState createState() => _ListViewPitfallState();
}

class _ListViewPitfallState extends State<ListViewPitfall> {
  final _content =
      List<String>.generate(64, (index) => "List item №${index + 1}");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _content.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
          title: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(child: Text(_content[index])),
              ClumsyWidget(
                // this widget will be recreated on each render
                // if you uncomment next line
                // key: UniqueKey(),
                title: _content[index],
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 6.0),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("delete"),
                onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  _content.removeAt(index);
                }),
              )
            ],
          ),
          onTap: () => print(_content[index]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ClumsyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const ClumsyWidget({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ClumsyWidgetState createState() => _ClumsyWidgetState();
}

class _ClumsyWidgetState extends State<ClumsyWidget> {
  String statefulTitle;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    statefulTitle = widget.title;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OutlineButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          statefulTitle = widget.title;
        });
      },
      child: Text(statefulTitle),
    );
  }
}
```

В левой части строк использован stateless виджет, а в правой, перед кнопкой удаления, stateful. При удалении строки наблюдается рассогласование левой и правой части у расположенных ниже элементов. Если прокрутить список до конца и обратно, то рассогласование исчезает. Stateful виджет сделан кнопкой, при клике которой состояние обновляется из параметров виджета. Кроме того, в коде есть закоментированный фрагмент с использованием **UniqueKey** в качестве "костыля".

Comment: Спасибо! Очень точное описание решения.